# Extend method of parent-class in child

Tags: kotlin, oop, inheritance

I got a short question:
Is it possible to extend a method of a child-class with extra parameters? The original method is defined in the parent-class.

The idea is to declare a base functionality which every file has to be checked. Then child-classes should just extend the parent class with extra functionality based on the typical Parameters like csv(columnCount, header, ...).

For example:

```
abstract class DataValidator {
    fun checkIfFileDoesExist(fileName: String, fileExtension: String): Boolean {
        val file = Path(fileName)

        return when {
            file.notExists() -> false
            file.extension != fileExtension -> false
            else -> true
        }
    }
 }

class CsvValidator: DataValidator() {
    override fun checkIfCsvFileDoesExist(
        fileName: String,
        fileExtension: String,
        additionallyParameter: String
    ): Boolean {
        var result = super.checkIfFileDoesExist(fileName, fileExtension)
        // processing with additionallyParameter
        return false
    }
}
```

The ide throws an error, but how is such a problem solved?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is not possible in Java or Kotlin to *override* a method with a different signature. You can *overload* methods, i.e. have multiple signatures, and override them individually, but I don't think this is what you are looking for.

Without understanding the meaning of your `additionalParameter` it is difficult to suggest a way to model this. Is this parameter only relevant for CSV files?

One possible approach would be to move parameters to the constructor, and create an abstract method in your base class, given the `additionalParameter` is common to all possible implementations.

```
abstract class DataValidator(
    val fileName: String,
    val fileExtension: String
) {
    fun checkIfFileDoesExist(): Boolean {
        val file = Path(fileName)

        return when {
            file.notExists() -> false
            file.extension != fileExtension -> false
            else -> true
        }
    }

    abstract fun validateFile(additionalParameter: String): Boolean
}

class CsvValidator(fileName: String, fileExtension: String) : DataValidator(fileName, fileExtension) {
    override fun validateFile(
        additionalParameter: String
    ): Boolean {
        if (checkIfFileDoesExist()) {
            // processing with additionalParameter
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
val validator = CsvValidator("myFile", "csv")
validator.validateFile("additionalParameter")
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake. additionalParameter like columnCount, or headerNames. Parameters which are typicaly JUST for csv files.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this aproach.

```
abstract class DataValidator {
    fun checkIfFileDoesExist(fileName: String, fileExtension: String): Boolean {
        val file = Path(fileName)

        return when {
            file.notExists() -> false
            file.extension != fileExtension -> false
            else -> true
        }
    }
 }

class CsvValidator: DataValidator() {
    fun checkIfCsvFileDoesExist(
        fileName: String,
        fileExtension: String,
        additionallyParameter: String
    ): Boolean {
        var result = super.checkIfFileDoesExist(fileName, fileExtension)
        // processing with additionallyParameter
        return false
    }
}
```